# perl 5.28.x compilation: Failed test 'timelocal year for 1970 1 2 0 0 0'

Tags: perl, installation, makefile, compilation, local

In Linux, installation of perl is failing while running make test command for Local module

```
[user@hostname perl-5.28.3]$  make test
cpan/Time-Local/t/Local ........................................ #   Failed test 'timelocal year for 1970 1 2 0 0 0'
#   at t/Local.t line 109.
#          got: '170'
#     expected: '70'
#   Failed test 'timegm year for 1970 1 2 0 0 0'
#   at t/Local.t line 124.
#          got: '170'
#     expected: '70'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 187.
FAILED at test 6
```

System date is set correctly in my system

```
[user@hostname perl-5.28.3]$ date
Mon Feb 14 07:38:07 PST 2022
```

are there any workaround/patch exists for perl-5.28.x release for this issue?

make test failure:

```
[user@hostname perl-5.28.3]$ t/TEST ../cpan/Time-Local/t/Local.t
t/../cpan/Time-Local/t/Local ... #   Failed test 'timelocal year for 1970 1 2 0 0 0'
#   at t/Local.t line 109.
#          got: '170'
#     expected: '70'
#   Failed test 'timegm year for 1970 1 2 0 0 0'
#   at t/Local.t line 124.
#          got: '170'
#     expected: '70'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 187.
FAILED at test 6
Failed 1 test out of 0, 0.00% okay.
        ../cpan/Time-Local/t/Local.t
```

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you get Perl to fail to install on Linux? lol. Sorry, no time to dig right now.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed a few years ago -- [Time::Local changes](https://metacpan.org/dist/Time-Local/changes#L34) -- and made it into Perl in 5.30: ["Time::Local has been upgraded from version 1.25 to 1.28."](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perldelta#Updated-Modules-and-Pragmata).

Comment: @Jim Davis Weird, cause I just installed 5.28.3 (like 30 minutes ago) without issue. I used perlbrew, so it's possible it patched something. /// Upd: Yup: `patching cpan/Time-Local/t/Local.t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is merely a badly written test which can be safely ignored.

The test was fixed in the newer version of Time::Local than the one bundled with perl-5.28.3. You could always install that version afterwards using `cpan Time::Local`.

---

If you insist on a clean install, you can run the following command:

```sh
patchperl 5.28.3 /path/to/untarred/perl/source/perl-5.28.3
```

It requires a Perl with Devel::PatchPerl installed. It installs the following patch:

```
--- cpan/Time-Local/t/Local.t
+++ cpan/Time-Local/t/Local.t
@@ -85,19 +85,17 @@ my $epoch_is_64

 for ( @time, @neg_time ) {
     my ( $year, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec ) = @$_;
-    $year -= 1900;
     $mon--;

 SKIP: {
         skip '1970 test on VOS fails.', 12
-            if $^O eq 'vos' && $year == 70;
+            if $^O eq 'vos' && $year == 1970;
         skip 'this platform does not support negative epochs.', 12
-            if $year < 70 && !$neg_epoch_ok;
+            if $year < 1970 && !$neg_epoch_ok;

         # Test timelocal()
         {
-            my $year_in = $year < 70 ? $year + 1900 : $year;
-            my $time = timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year_in );
+            my $time = timelocal( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year );

             my ( $s, $m, $h, $D, $M, $Y ) = localtime($time);

@@ -106,13 +104,12 @@ SKIP: {
             is( $h, $hour,     "timelocal hour for @$_" );
             is( $D, $mday,     "timelocal day for @$_" );
             is( $M, $mon,      "timelocal month for @$_" );
-            is( $Y, $year,     "timelocal year for @$_" );
+            is( $Y, $year - 1900,     "timelocal year for @$_" );
         }

         # Test timegm()
         {
-            my $year_in = $year < 70 ? $year + 1900 : $year;
-            my $time = timegm( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year_in );
+            my $time = timegm( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year );

             my ( $s, $m, $h, $D, $M, $Y ) = gmtime($time);

@@ -121,14 +118,13 @@ SKIP: {
             is( $h, $hour,     "timegm hour for @$_" );
             is( $D, $mday,     "timegm day for @$_" );
             is( $M, $mon,      "timegm month for @$_" );
-            is( $Y, $year,     "timegm year for @$_" );
+            is( $Y, $year - 1900,     "timegm year for @$_" );
         }
     }
 }

 for (@bad_time) {
     my ( $year, $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec ) = @$_;
-    $year -= 1900;
     $mon--;

     eval { timegm( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year ) };
@@ -229,6 +225,30 @@ SKIP:
     );
 }

+# 2-digit years
+{
+       my $current_year = ( localtime() )[5];
+       my $pre_break    = ( $current_year + 49 ) - 100;
+       my $break        = ( $current_year + 50 ) - 100;
+       my $post_break   = ( $current_year + 51 ) - 100;
+
+       is(
+               ( ( localtime( timelocal( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $pre_break ) ) )[5] ),
+               $pre_break + 100,
+               "year $pre_break is treated as next century",
+       );
+       is(
+               ( ( localtime( timelocal( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $break ) ) )[5] ),
+               $break + 100,
+               "year $break is treated as next century",
+       );
+       is(
+               ( ( localtime( timelocal( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $post_break ) ) )[5] ),
+               $post_break,
+               "year $post_break is treated as current century",
+       );
+}
+
 SKIP:
 {
     skip 'These tests only run for the package maintainer.', 8
```